# Apply select2 on dynamically loaded external html component

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

When loading a page, it loads another html page inside it and the html page contains select, which I want to apply select2 on it.

The very basic page contains

```
<select class="selectAddItem" id="selectAddItem" name="selectAddItem" style="width: 150px;" class="required">
  <option value="">--- Please Select---</option>
  <option value="1">Movie</option>
  <option value="2">Actor or Actress</option>
</select>
<div class="well" id="well"></div>
```

and when I select an item, it loads an external html page inside by

```
$(document).on('change','#selectAddItem',function(){
  if(this.value==1) {
    $("#well").load("/showAddMovie");
  } else {
    $("#well").load("/showAddActor");
  }
  $.getScript("../static/js/select2.min.js");
  $.getScript("../static/js/additem.js");
  $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
      width: "80%",
      tags: true
  });;
});
```

The showAddMovie will load html page containing select and I want to apply select 2 on the loaded page. The external html contains something like below.

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
  <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
  <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

However, select2 is not applied in my code. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Both `.load` and `.getScript` are async, you need a callback when both are complere before you call `.select2()`. I would use the success function of `.load` and remove the lazy loading of select2 and put it directly in the page as a standard include.

Answer (score 0):

This call is an ajax call `$("#well").load("/showAddMovie");`

You need to specify callback function in the second parameter so that once the data is loaded then you do further processing inside the callback function.
`$("#well").load("/showAddMovie", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt == "success")
            console.log("loaded successfully!");
        if(statusTxt == "error")
            console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });`

Also as suggested by `MrCode` that `$.getScript` is also async call, you may want to use `$.when` to combine async calls and do processing once all calls are resolved.